# Rockafellar's Theorem 20.1

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 20.1 from Rockafellar's classic book "Convex Analysis".

My issue is the argument:

> ..., and hence
>   $$\text{dom(}g_1)\cap\text{ri(dom}(g_2))\not=\varnothing.$$
>   This implies that, for the affine hull M of $\text{dom}(g_2)$,
>   $$\text{ri(dom(}g_1)\cap M)\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2))\not=\varnothing.$$

My thought is, by Corollary 6.5.1,
$$\text{ri(dom(}g1)\cap M)=\text{ri(dom(}g_1))\cap M.$$
Thus, since $\text{dom}(g_2)\subseteq M$,
$$\text{ri(dom(}g_1)\cap M)\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2))\\= \text{ri(dom(}g_1))\cap M\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2))\\=\text{ri(dom(}g_1))\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2)).$$

And then we have nothing to say (?)

Any guidance will be really helpful!

Comment: To apply Corollary 6.5.1, you already need $M$ to contain a point of ri(dom($g_1$)).

Comment: You cannot use Corollary 6.5.1. It does not apply to dom($g_1$)=$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 \geq 0, x_2 = 0\}$ and dom($g_2$)=$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 = 0\}$ (although the quoted argument from the book is still true).

Comment: I see.. I just wanted to know the reason why the quoted argument is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof goes along these lines. Define
$$
\begin{align}
L &= \text{aff dom(}g_1\text{)} \\ 
M &= \text{aff dom(}g_2\text{)} \\ 
S &= \text{dom(}g_1)\cap\text{ri(dom}(g_2)) \\
T &= \text{ri(dom(}g_1))\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2))\\
U &= [\text{dom(}g_1)\backslash\text{ri(dom(}g_1))]\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2))\\
V &= \text{ri(dom(}g_1)\cap M)\cap\text{ri(dom(}g_2)).
\end{align}
$$
Note that $x\in T$ implies $x\in V$ by corollary 6.5.1. We therefore only have to consider the case $S\not=\emptyset$ but $T=\emptyset$. Then $x \in U$ implies $x \in V$.

Comment: I agree, but the difficult part should be to prove that $x\in U$ implies $x\in V$.

Comment: Not really. The intersection in $U$ is either one point or multiple points. The first case is straightforward, for the second case, the line segment between those points has to be in $V$. Intuitively speaking :)

Comment: And where did you use that $\text{dom}(g_1)$ is polyhedral? This condition is necessary for this claim, isn't it? However, I do not disagree with your argument.

Comment: It does not seem to be necessary for this particular claim. It's used later in the proof (top of p. 181).